# T-SQL: Getting all the tables having one column called XXX

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to have all the tables having one column called XXX

I've tried the following query but it's not working.

```
SELECT object_id
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE name = 'XXX';
```

Comment: "it's not working" - what does it mean?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: pressing F5 is aking me to create a report file

Comment: "having one column called XXX" - is that "among the columns in those tables, they have a column called XXX" or "these tables have exactly one column, and it's named XXX"?

Comment: @Revious open a brand new query window and try again. It sounds like you've clicked on the "Results to File" button (CTRL+SHIFT+F).

Comment: @gvee: you are rigth, solved.

Comment: @Revious sorted. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT table_schema
     , table_name
     , column_name
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  column_name LIKE '%test%'
```

You've mentioned in your question comments that "it's not working" =

> pressing F5 is aking me to create a report file

In Management Studio you have a few options for what to do with your query results:

[image]

1. Results to Text           `CTRL + T`
2. Results to Grid (default) `CTRL + D`
3. Results to File           `CTRL + SHIFT + F`

Sounds like you've hit the "Results to File" button (or key combination).

Comment: Plus 1 for being able to glean some information from that question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one that will grab both the column and the table it belongs to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT so.name AS tablename, sc.name AS columnname 
FROM syscolumns sc
INNER JOIN sysobjects so
ON so.id=sc.id
WHERE sc.name LIKE '%XXX%'
ORDER BY so.name, sc.name
```